# How to open top.location.href url in a new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.location

I had a function in my application which calls other domain url, I'm struggling to open that url in a new window when the function is executed.

sample code:

```
$('#btn').onClick(function(){ //This code is in my application.
//callOtherfn is a function from external javascript code that i cant change, 
 //because that is from other source.     
 callOtherfn({
   'param1':'param1',
    'param2':'param2'
  })   
});

//external javascript library  sample.js
  function callOtherfn(params){
   top.window.location = "www.sample.com";
  }
```

Now my question is, can it be possible to open "www.sample.com" in a new window after calling "callotherfn" without disturbing my app? Right now it is opening in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

open in a new window:

```
  function callOtherfn(params){
   window.open("www.sample.com", '_blank', "");
  }
```

Comment: I dont have access to this code, That is from other library. Im' calling it from my app

Comment: Don't call that function. Write your own. If instead the external library is calling the function, you can change the object within your code like BuggeredLibrary.callOtherfn =

Comment: Thing is that i had to call that function for sure in my case. I'm thinking to do something like "beforeonload" and call the "sample.com" to open in a new window